# Spree - Disable checkout's country selection and modify the checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I need to create an online shop to sell some e-learning services, mostly online courses.

I'm thinking to start with Spree, so I've installed it and I started playing with the configuration, I'm also starting with Ruby and RoR, and I plan to carry out all my next works on this platform that I really like.

I'm just curious to know if it's a good idea to start with a complete solution like Spree to sell this kind of products. I'd need to change some checkout steps, for example there is no need to deliver the things, since they are services (online courses).
Then I'd like to disable the country selection because the ecommerce will just sell in our country and it's useless to allow this selection.

How can I do it?

Then I'd like to allow users to choose between a one-time payment and a recurring billing solution.

Can you help me to understand what I need to do this?

At a first glance it seems a lot of work (beside the fact that I'm new with the framework and with the language -coming from python, php, c++).

I'm using the latest version of spree from their git repo with rails 3.2.3 (ruby 1.9.3 under RVM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can modify the checkout steps have a look at http://guides.spreecommerce.com/checkout.html#checkout-customization on how to do this.

On the payments side good luck! I have been struggling with this for a while now and there doesn't seem to be much out there. I will update this if I am able to find anything solid.

If you are new to ruby on rails I would suggest that you take some time to familiarise your self with ruby on rails first before diving into spree as this will save you alot of time in the long run.

if you are running the latest verison of spree(edge) rather then the latest released version please be careful.

Thanks

Ash

Comment: Thanks for the info! I needed to install it via git because previous version doesn't seem to work with 3.2.3 and googling for an answer I got that Rails 3.2.3 will be official supported starting with the v1.1.0 (btw the bundler installs the version 0.40.0 -very old-).